# Residual plot is tight to zero, but low R2 score

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, regression

Hi I am a beginner at data science, and currently trying to use Gradient Boost Regressor to predict car price based on several attribute such as machine capacity, car brand, car type etc.

I am following this tutorial: https://github.com/PaacMaan/cars-price-predictor/blob/master/cars_price_predictor.ipynb

I got a low R2 score and plotted the residual vs predicted value, what i am confused with is even though my residual value is close to zero (as showed on the graph) my r2_score is low. Can anyone kindly explain this to me?
[image: residual vs predicted]

here is my r2 score

r2_score: 0.38

and the code i am using

```
car_df_encoded = pd.get_dummies(car_df_encoded, columns=['Store_Loc','Brand','Type','Transmission'], prefix = ['Store_Loc','Brand','Type','Transmission'])
price= car_df_encoded.pop('Price')


x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(car_df_encoded, harga, test_size=0.25)

gbr = GradientBoostingRegressor(loss='huber', max_depth=5, max_features=None,min_samples_leaf=8, min_samples_split=6, n_estimators=150,random_state=42)
gbr.fit (x_train, y_train)
predicted = gbr.predict(x_test)
residual = y_test - predicted
```

Tried using cross validation as well

```
scores = cross_val_score(gbr, car_df_encoded, harga, cv=4, scoring='r2')
print('\nMean Score:')
print(scores.mean())
```

and my mean r2 score is

```
Cross Validation Scores:
[0.76621245 0.41771035 0.35744057 0.73955563]

Mean Score:
0.5702297501214788
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the plot there is a huge outlier in your residual. Plus taking into account that your cross-validation sometimes shows quite good results (0.77, 0.74) and sometimes not so great (0.42, 0.36) I would first try to remove that outlier from your data and see what you get.

Answer (score 2):

Your residuals don't seem like they're so close to zero. Look on the x-axis of your histogram. Your interquartile range is hundreds of thousands if not a couple million, so you have many residuals that are quite enormous. Yes, you're working with large numbers, but the tight clustering on your graphs only looks tight on a gigantic scale. I would say that this is why you have gotten tight-looking fits but an $R^2$ value that is not strong enough. The outlier idea by Marat Seroglazov is interesting, but it looks like you should have enough data to cushion that outlier effect.

I am quite curious about the interquartile range of your residuals.

Answer (score 1):

Try plotting `log` of your residual instead, then you can get a clearer picture on how large your residuals are. With the gigantic outlier in your current plot, it is hard to see how large other residuals are. And some of yours are really large.